# Call viewHolder method from Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview in Fragment. On scroll change I want to call a method in view holder of the Adapter. How can I get the view holder instance.

```
 recyclerview_home_view.apply {
        val config = resources.configuration
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
            orientation = HORIZONTAL
            when {
                config.layoutDirection == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL -> {
                    reverseLayout = true
                    page_indicator.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR
                }
            }
        }


override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {

                (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).apply {

// I want to call the view holder method from here

}

}
```

Comment: You don't, you modify the data and notify the adapter of data change.

Comment: I need to set the focus on recyclerview child, from Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call the viewholder. Instead, you should modify the data and notify that the data changed with notifydatasetchanged().

Comment: I need to set the focus on recyclerview child, from Fragment